# EF Core 2 SQL scalar function value as part of insert/create

Tags: sql-server, ef-core-2.1

I am using EFCore 2.1 to create a record. I would like one field to be populated from a value generated from a scalar function.

```
 public async Task<FraudClaim> CreateFraudClaimAsync(FraudClaim fraudClaim)
    {
        fraudClaim.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
        fraudClaim.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        fraudClaim.Deleted = false;
        fraudClaim.FraudReportNumber 
        =ScalarFunctionsHelpers.GetFraudReportNumber(); //Value From Scalar 
             Function
        _dbcontext.Add(fraudClaim);

        await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return fraudClaim;
    }
```

The SQL that I would like generated would be similar to-

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[FraudClaims]
       ([AddedDate]
       ,[UpdatedDate]
       ,[UpdatedBy]
       ,[Deleted]
       ,[FraudReportNumber]
       ,[WagersClaimNumber]
       ,[FraudNotificationDate]
  )
      VALUES
       (getdate()
       ,getdate()
       ,'HD'
       ,0
       , [dbo].[ufnGetFraudReportNumber]()
       ,1
       ,getdate()
       )
```

I believe I can do this by breaking up the call the function to retrieve the value first then set the value but I was hoping to do it all in one trip.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: How did you solve this?